# GridBagLayout inside a JPanel and JPanel inside GridBagLayout

Tags: java, swing, gridbaglayout

I have got two classes in Java:

- class1 calls multiple instances of class2.
- class2 extends JPanel
  So I want to set `GridBagLayout` in class1, so I can add the instances of the class2 to the list.

My code is as follow:

---

Class1

---

```
class2 one = new class2();
class2 two = new class2();

this.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();

gbc.insets = new Insets(6,2,6,40);

gbc.gridx = 0;
this.add(new JLabel("Name"), gbc);
gbc.gridx = 1;
this.add(new JLabel("Surname"), gbc);
gbc.gridx = 2;
this.add(new JLabel("Age"), gbc);

gbc.gridx = 0;

gbc.gridy = 1;
this.add(one, gbc);     

gbc.gridy = 2;
this.add(two, gbc);
```

---

Class2 extends JPanel

---

```
this.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
GridBagConstraints gridBagCons = new GridBagConstraints();

gridBagCons.insets = new Insets(6,2,6,4);

gridBagCons.gridx = 0;
this.add(new JTextField(10), gridBagCons);
gridBagCons.gridx = 1;
this.add(new JTextField(10), gridBagCons);
gridBagCons.gridx = 2;
this.add(new JTextField(10), gridBagCons);
```

So, it doesn't work, it shows the titles: name, surname and age as I wanted, and the other two panels imported from class2 inside the first column of the GridBagLayout of class1. 
I want to align the titles to the textfields imported from class2.

Please, could you have a look for me.

Comment: could be nice question about nested layout in the case you post an SSCCE / MCVE / MCTRE, short, runnable, compilable

Comment: Can you draw or explain what you want it to look like?

Comment: @mKorbel I have modified the question a little bit, so it is more clear. I now need to align the titles of class1 to the textfields from class2

Answer (score 0):

You need to set `gridwidth` on the `GridBagConstraints`. Your examples create a 3x3 grid. The titles are in the first row. On the second row, the first position contains the whole `Class2` panel, and columns 2 and 3 have nothing. The same for the 3rd row.

Put

`gbc.gridWidth = 3;`

before adding `Class2` panels.

To align the textfields, put

```
gbc.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
gbc.weightx = 1;
```

for each label of the "header" and each text field of Class 2. Manually setting insets will not resize correctly.

Comment: This will not align the text fields with the titles if that's actually how he wants it.

Comment: This answer helped me to organize well. However @user1803551 is right, it didnt align the textfields below the titles. Could you please help me aligning them below the classes.

Comment: Edited the answer. Be careful when setting insets manually. Take into account there is one GridBagLayout for panel of Class1 and one for each panel of Class2.

Answer (score -1):

You can manually adjust the insets

```
gbc.insets = new Insets(6,2,6,90);
gbc.gridx = 0;
this.add(new JLabel("Name"), gbc);
gbc.insets = new Insets(6,0,6,-20);
gbc.gridx = 1;
this.add(new JLabel("Surname"), gbc);
gbc.insets = new Insets(6,0,6,0);
gbc.gridx = 2;
this.add(new JLabel("Age"), gbc);

gbc.gridx = 0;
gbc.gridwidth = 3;

gbc.gridy = 1;
this.add(one, gbc);     
gbc.gridy = 2;
this.add(two, gbc);
```

Although you will probably be better off not using the second class and adding the text fields in another way depending on your implementation.

---

**Edit:** Here is a way to dynamically add fields using `GridLayout`

```
public class AddingFields {

    static GridLayout gl = new GridLayout(2, 3, 20, 10);
    static JFrame frame = new JFrame();

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        new AddingFields();
        createAdderFrame();
    }

    AddingFields() {

        frame.setLayout(gl);

        frame.add(new JLabel("Name"));
        frame.add(new JLabel("Surname"));
        frame.add(new JLabel("Age"));

        frame.add(new JTextField(10));
        frame.add(new JTextField(10));
        frame.add(new JTextField(10));

        frame.pack();
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    static void createAdderFrame() {

        JFrame adder = new JFrame();
        JButton addButton = new JButton("Add row");
        adder.add(addButton);
        addButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

                gl.setRows(gl.getRows() + 1);
                frame.add(new JTextField(10));
                frame.add(new JTextField(10));
                frame.add(new JTextField(10));
                frame.pack();
            }
        });
        adder.pack();
        adder.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Comment: It is getting messy now. I need to find another way to not set GidBagLayount on class2 and only have on class1. Any ideas?

Comment: What are you trying to get eventually? Dynamically adding rows? You have to use a specific layout? You can use `GridLayout` to get a similar result.

Comment: yes, so I want to dynamically add rows, and then each textfield from class2 should be below its respective title

Comment: I edited my answer to give an example with `GridLayout`. There are other ways of course.